# which extension just modified on my files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any ways to know which extension has modified my files.

I have a problem where once I move a file to another folder all my paths are  being rewritten.from like `import from '../component/hello.js'` to 'import from 'component/hello.js'`

It is really annoying since it would do it for all the files in my app.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Extension Bisect` feature in v1.52, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65177115/836330

---

I am currently unable to test this but see this setting:

> // Enable/disable automatic updating of import paths when you rename or move a file in VS Code. Possible values are: 'prompt' on each rename, 'always' update paths automatically, and 'never' rename paths and don't prompt me. Requires using TypeScript 2.9 or newer in the workspace.

```
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "prompt",
```

"`prompt`" is the default so you *should* be seeing that if this is the cause of the updating of your import paths.  In any case, try "`never`".

Comment: And similar if you are using typescript:   "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "prompt", etc.