# How to disable Visual Studio Code changes import automatically on React Native?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code with React Native extension. I do not remember what it asked but I unfortunately clicked yes to the prompted question and form that point VS Code is changing the import of react and react-native paths to exact location in node_modules folder. 
It is quite annoying and I cannot find how to disable it. 
Does anyone know how to stop automatic changing of import lines on VS Code?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449890/which-extension-just-modified-on-my-files/51452161#51452161  Does it help?

Answer (score -1):

You can find the configurations at **User Settings**.

> File -> Preferences -> Settings

At there, you can remove the ones you want to reset.

Comment: The thing is I do not know which one it is:)