# Prevent VSCode/TypeScript from Automatically Changing Imports for the Entire Project

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

This is the 3rd time that somewhere/somehow while I'm working VSCode/TypeScript has taken the initiative to go through the entire project and update the imports to use non-relative paths.

Using non-relative paths like `@app`, `@shared`, `@core`, etc is great since it cleans up the imports, but when it occurs automatically project-wide instead of occurring only for new imports we get around 400 unstaged file changes, and need to work through reverting them to find the files that were being worked on since a commit like this would cause a bunch of merge conflicts.

I thought maybe I'm hitting some sort of short cut key in VSCode, but I can't figure out if that's true.  Is there a way to prevent the VSCode/TypeScript from automatically updating all the imports throughout a project?  We just want to use this feature for new imports during development as they are added, or manually update old imports, but not have them randomly updated project-wide.

There are no VSCode packages installed that might perform this action.

Comment: Why would you vote to close this question?

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449890/which-extension-just-modified-on-my-files/51452161#51452161

Comment: I don't think so since I didn't move any files.  I was just typing and then I can hear my CPU fan start spinning up then ~400 files open in VSCode since they've now had their imports all updated, but I'll see if that leads to another property under JavaScript in the VSCode settings

Comment: Switch to WebStorm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Prevent VSCode/TypeScript from Automatically Changing Imports for the Entire Project

The user setting is `typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled` and `javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled`. Switch off with value `"never"` e.g.

```
"typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never"
```

Comment: Please review the comments.