# How to stop VSCode from changing import paths on moving file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My `import react from 'react'`

got changed to

`import React from '../../../../../../../Library/Caches/typescript/2.9/node_modules/@types/react';`

How do i revert this? I accidentally hit YES when VSCode asked me.

Comment: Ctrl+Z ? Discard changes in your VCS ?

Comment: haha. I mean to revert the setting, that keeps doing this, not the actual change.

Comment: Duplicate of a few questions since the last vscode update, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449890/which-extension-just-modified-on-my-files/51452161#51452161

Comment: Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51469456/prevent-vscode-typescript-from-automatically-changing-imports-for-the-entire-pro/51470572#comment89909491_51470572

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> How to stop VSCode from changing import paths on moving file?

Open VSCode settings (menu -> File -> Preferences -> Settings) and search for `typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled`.
Click on the pen icon in the gutter of the configuration line and choose `prompt` or `never`.

> How do i revert this? I accidentally hit YES when VSCode asked me.

I'm afraid there is no way to undo this change. VSCode does the refactoring in all files where the moved files is included but afaik it doesn't provide a way to undo such operations.

Comment: `never` tells it to not update the imports when you rename a file. By default it probably is `prompt` (it have asked you, isn't it?)

Comment: It asked first time if `it should change the reference values` and I picked `always change` option. Once you set `always change` VS code starts changing references always by default on every rename and moving file.

Now I set it to `never` and it asks again once on moving file then had to again say `never change reference` and it worked.