# VSCode automatically breaking paths in Node.js app

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

All of a sudden VSCode has decided to automatically break my Node app paths. It's changing this line in server.ts:

```
import app from './app';
```

to this version which doesn't work:

```
import app from 'app';
```

It also wants to change other paths. For example:

```
import myCtrl = require('../controllers/my');
```

to the broken:

```
import myCtrl = require('controllers/my');
```

Is this some kind of IDE configuration vs app config conflict? I've looked but I can't find the issue.

Edit: It's changing about 12-15 files, so it's not just a quick undo. I have to check which changes I can just discard.

I don't want to just turn off the update imports paths options since it was useful. I have it on prompt right now but I can't use it because of this issue.

Comment: VSCode does it when you paste new code? when VSCode over-zealously formats my code, a simple Ctrl+z helps undo it

Comment: Seems to be a few of these variants popping up since the last update - possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449890/which-extension-just-modified-on-my-files/51452161#51452161 I would be interested in  knowing if setting the setting referred to in that answer to "never" fixes your problem.

Comment: @mark it does look similar. I've changed it to prompt but I can't use it which sucks. when it worked, it was really handy