# How do I determine which VS Code extension is causing a crash?

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Context**

I'm using VS Code in a fairly large repo and my extension host keeps crashing. When I run the editor with extensions disabled I'm able to work without interruption. During these times VS Code is using the vast majority of my machines CPU.

**Question**

Is there a way for me to inspect which extension is the culprit causing the crashes?

Comment: there's an open issue on that https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84940

Comment: That bug is about opening large files. The issue here is in a large repo, but I think the overall question is how to determine what extension is causing the crash.

Answer (score 14):

There is a new feature coming in v1.52 - `Extension Bisect` - which could help with determining which extension is causing  an issue.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_52.md#trouble-shooting-extension-bisect

> ... sometimes extensions misbehave and sometimes it isn't obvious if an
> issue is caused by an extension and if so by which extension. Until
> today, you needed to disable all extensions and then one by one
> re-enable extensions to find a bad extension. This process is now
> getting easy with a new feature called "Extension Bisect". It uses the
> binary search algorithm to quickly identify an extension that causes
> trouble. In essence, it disables half your extensions and asks you to
> check for the issue you were seeing. If the issue is gone the bad
> extension must have been in the list of disabled extensions, otherwise
> in the list of enabled extensions. This process is now repeated on the
> list, which must contain the bad extension until only a single
> extension is left.
>
> You can start extension bisect via Start Extension Bisect. It then
> guide through the process of repeatedly disabling and re-enabling
> extensions. After each reload you will be prompted to confirm if the
> issue is still there.

---

> "Extension Bisect" will repeatedly ask you to check if the issue is
> still there or not. You can always abort via Stop Bisect and when
> having dismissed the bisect notification you can continue via Continue
> Extension Bisect.

see images at the release note link.

Comment: Wow, that actually works really well. Helped me very quickly track down an extension which was causing VS code to freeze.

Answer (score 0):

When the extension host crashes, you should get a popup window that asks to debug the process or restart the extension host. If you debug the process, you will see a number of errors. Reviewing each error will identify the bad extension.