How to determine which extension is causing a problem?
My VS Code was misbehaving where every time I saved any file it gave the error:

The content of the file is newer. Please compare your version with the file contents.

The problem went away when I ran VS Code with all extensions disabled, but I had no clue which extension was to blame.
I debugged it by just disabling half my extensions and trying to reproduce the problem, then re-enabling half of those disabled ones if it went away, and repeating this binary search style until I found which extension was causing the issue. Is there a better way? I know the command showRuntimeExtensions gives the running extensions but it is still a large list. Is there a way to see which extensions are executing code at any given moment, so I could see which ones are doing something specifically when I save a file and trigger the error?

That's how https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect

was tempted to close as dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59277252/11107541, but crashes are a different issue and there are different mechanisms to diagnose them.

Do an extension bisect. Open the command palette and run Help: Start Extension Bisect. It will run you through something like an A/B binary search of the extensions to figure out which one is resulting in an observed behaviour.

Is there a way to see which extensions are executing code at any given moment

The extensions view should reflect this. Disabled extensions will be greyed out, and those that need a reload to be disabled will have an indicator saying so. Or you can put @enabled in the search bar there.
Alternatively, you can run Developer: Show Running Extensions in the command palette.

command pallet ctr + shift + p  in windows command + shift + p in mac. just enter Bisect.

@nabinsademba I don't give a keybinding is because I tell people about the command palette in countless posts, and there are multiple keybindings. for some reason, many people don't know that you can use F1. also, the command center is enabled by default since several versions ago, so you can use the mouse as well. and the palette is so fundamental that if I felt that it had a place in ~all my answers, I'd tell people to make an easier to reach binding for themselves

you are right, but i was just adding the  keybindings because when you search how to open command pallet in vscode that is the first thing it will show :)

@nabinsademba the reader shouldn't need to search. it's in the first sentence of the linked resource on "command palette".
